# How to send peer to peer message in hyperledger aries while I can achive the basic messaging with server to mobile device

Tags: xamarin.forms, blockchain, hyperledger, messaging

In which way we can achieve peer to peer message in hyperledger aries and I have done basic messaging from mobile device to server on xamarin. using _messageService.SendReceiveAsync .